# Finding the distance between incenter and centroid of a triangle

Tags: geometry

I have problem about solving this homework:

> In any given triangle, find the distance between the centroid and the incenter.

I have no idea which properties to use to find it. Can you help me please? :(

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot think of any well-known formula for that. Can you give more of the triangle you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple to tackle through exact [barycentric coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html):
$$ G=\frac{A+B+C}{3},\qquad I=\frac{aA+bB+cC}{a+b+c} \tag{1}$$
give:
$$ 3(a+b+c)(G-I) = (b+c-2a) A + (a+c-2b) B + (a+b-2c) C \tag{2}$$
and by assuming that the origin is in the circumcenter $O$ we get:

$$ 9(a+b+c)^2\left\|G-I\right\|^2 = 6R^2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)+\ldots \tag{3}$$
that boils down to [a quite complicated expression](http://www.gogeometry.com/center/distance_incenter_centroid_formula_sides.htm).

Comment: I think your $\ldots$ can be substantially simplified. One may use the law of cosines to express the dot product of $A$ and $B$ as $2A\cdot B =2R^2-c^2$, and similarly for the other two products. With this in mind, the coefficient of the $R^2$ term becomes $$a'^2+b'^2+c'^2+2a'b'+2b'c'+2a'c'=(a'+b'+c')^2$$ where $a',b',c'$ are the coefficients of $A,B,C$ respectively in equation (2). But $a'+b'+c'=0$, so the circumradius drops out entirely. What remains gives the expression given in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b,c -$ a sides of the triangle and $d -$ the distance between the centroid and the incenter . Then 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b, c$ be sides of a triangle.

$GI$ (the distance between the centroid and the incenter):

$GI=\frac{1}{3}·\sqrt{5·r^2-16·R·r+s^2}$

where $r$ (inradius), $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$ (semiperimeter) and $R$ (circumradius).